# Joomla : 404 pages showing homepage content

Tags: http-status-code-404, joomla1.5

I have a site in joomla (version 1.5.23), wherein any url which isn't present shows content of homepage (and its 200 ok). How do i get it to go to a 404  page

ex. www.example.com/sdfsdf or www.example.com/blahblah all shows homepage content.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards,

Sushil

Answer (score 1):

These methods work. Different explanation, but the same concept.

[Method](http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_create_a_custom_404_page_not_found_page_in_Joomla.html)

[Original Joomla! doc](http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_error_pages)

If your using Apache check the presence of the following line and all 404 errors will be redirected to your homepage
Code:
ErrorDocument 404 index.php

Solution about a similar problem: [Joomla! forum link](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=282063)